# Substitute Deformable Attention with Deformable Convolution

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Bascially, I feel these two modules are connected and the topic is feasible. But I just haven't figure out how. How to convert GridSample to Convolution window and how to design the convolution kernel and its slides ?

I have not tried anything yet except some manuscripts. But I would keep posting updates here.